# How to save Quartz executed jobs?

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

One problem, after executed jobs, quartz delete jobs from database qrtz_triggers table, but in specific situation needed to repeat job which is failed.

Is any configuration options or way to store jobs to another table after execute???

Thanks

Comment: If your job fails, you can decide to either make your job recoverable or in your job, upon failure, you can access the scheduler to reschedule your job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `JDBCJobStore`, your jobs are stored in a table like `QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS`, and your simple triggers are stored in `QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS`, your cron trigers are stored in `QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS`, and all the triggers are stored in `QRTZ_TRIGGERS`.

If you expect your job is durable and remains when no triggers are associated to the job, you should call `storeDurably(true)` when building your JobDetail. For example:

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob()
    .ofType(DataMapJob.class)
    .withIdentity("dataJob", "dataJobGroup")
    .storeDurably(true)
    .requestRecovery(true)
    .build();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: will storeDurably also store each execution history of a cron trigger?

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the durable flag is for. Durable jobs remain registered in Quartz even if there are no triggers associated with the job. On the other hand, non-durable jobs are automatically deleted by Quartz where there are no associated triggers (e.g. after all associated triggers fired and have been deleted by Quartz).

For details, you can refer to [JobDetailImpl javadoc](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/JobDetailImpl.html#setDurability(boolean)).